# On Flutter, how to convert MLKit InputImage to Image?

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

`google_mlkit_commons` define `InputImage`.

How can I convert `InputImage` to `Image` widget?

In this example, I'm using `camerawesome` for receiving the images from the camera and doing an analysis with mlkit text recognizer. The code works well, the mlkit recognizes text from the image received.

Now, I want to save the image where the text is recognized. An Image is created from `InputImage.bytes`, but when the image treats to show, in throws the exception `Failed to decode image. E/FlutterJNI(31225): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.`

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _textRecognizer = TextRecognizer();
  bool _isBusy = false;
  Image? _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Stack(
      children: [
        CameraAwesomeBuilder.previewOnly(
            imageAnalysisConfig: AnalysisConfig(
              androidOptions: const AndroidAnalysisOptions.nv21(
                width: 1024,
              ),
              maxFramesPerSecond: 5,
              autoStart: true,
            ),
            onImageForAnalysis: _processImage,
            builder: (CameraState cameraModeState, previewSize, previewRect) {
              return AwesomeCameraLayout(state: cameraModeState);
            }),
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: _image == null ? const SizedBox.shrink() : _image!,
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  Future<void> _processImage(AnalysisImage image) async {
    final InputImage inputImage = image.toInputImage();
    if (_isBusy) return;
    _isBusy = true;
    final RecognizedText recognizedText =
        await _textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);
    final String text = recognizedText.text.toLowerCase();
    if ((text.isNotEmpty) && (text.contains('hoje'))) {
      setState(() {
        _image = Image.memory(inputImage.bytes!);
      });
    }
    _isBusy = false;
  }
}


extension MLKitUtils on AnalysisImage {
  InputImage toInputImage() {
    final planeData =
        when(nv21: (img) => img.planes, bgra8888: (img) => img.planes)?.map(
      (plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: height,
          width: width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    return when(nv21: (image) {
      return InputImage.fromBytes(
        bytes: image.bytes,
        inputImageData: InputImageData(
          imageRotation: inputImageRotation,
          inputImageFormat: InputImageFormat.nv21,
          planeData: planeData,
          size: image.size,
        ),
      );
    }, bgra8888: (image) {
      final inputImageData = InputImageData(
        size: size,
        // FIXME: seems to be ignored on iOS...
        imageRotation: inputImageRotation,
        inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
        planeData: planeData,
      );

      return InputImage.fromBytes(
        bytes: image.bytes,
        inputImageData: inputImageData,
      );
    })!;
  }

  InputImageRotation get inputImageRotation =>
      InputImageRotation.values.byName(rotation.name);

  InputImageFormat get inputImageFormat {
    switch (format) {
      case InputAnalysisImageFormat.bgra8888:
        return InputImageFormat.bgra8888;
      case InputAnalysisImageFormat.nv21:
        return InputImageFormat.nv21;
      default:
        return InputImageFormat.yuv420;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this package . after use function "decodeYUV420SP" you can DartImage.encodeJpg it return Uint8List , so you can use Image.memory ...

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as DartImage;

DartImage.Image decodeYUV420SP(InputImage image) {
final width = image.metadata!.size.width.toInt();
final height = image.metadata!.size.height.toInt();

Uint8List yuv420sp = image.bytes!;
var rotationOfCamera = 0;
if (image.metadata != null && image.metadata!.rotation.rawValue != 0) {
  rotationOfCamera = image.metadata!.rotation.rawValue;
}
return decodeYUV420SP_from_camera(
    width, height, yuv420sp, rotationOfCamera);
}


DartImage.Image decodeYUV420SP_from_camera(
  int width, int height, Uint8List yuv420sp, int rotationOfCamera) {
var outImg =
DartImage.Image(width: width, height: height); // default numChannels is 3

final int frameSize = width * height;

for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
  int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
    int y = (0xff & yuv420sp[yp]) - 16;
    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    if ((i & 1) == 0) {
      v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
      u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
    }
    int y1192 = 1192 * y;
    int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
    int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
    int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

    if (r < 0) {
      r = 0;
    } else if (r > 262143) {
      r = 262143;
    }
    if (g < 0) {
      g = 0;
    } else if (g > 262143) {
      g = 262143;
    }
    if (b < 0) {
      b = 0;
    } else if (b > 262143) {
      b = 262143;
    }
    outImg.setPixelRgb(i, j, ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) >> 16,
        ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) >> 8, (b >> 10) & 0xff);
  }
}

if (rotationOfCamera != 0) {
  outImg = DartImage.copyRotate(outImg, angle: rotationOfCamera);
}
return outImg;  }
```

Comment: works in Android and iOS?

Answer (score -1):

I see that there is a way to get the object Uint8List from InputImage , from there several ways is offered to us to convert it into widget image, here is an example:

```
final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(yourFilePath);

final Widget imageWidget = Image.memory(inputImage.bytes);

// you can now use your widget
```

[Input image documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_mlkit_commons/latest/google_mlkit_commons/InputImage-class.html)

[Image memory documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html)

Comment: Doesn't work, it returns an exception: "Invalid image data"

Comment: can you share your please ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: can you share your code please ?